# Modal to open the specific record edit on click of link in jquery datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inlineeditsupport, modal, lightning-datatable, datatable.js

I have created a jquery datatable in salesforce. I want that when somebody click on the Id column in the datatable, it should open the edit page in a modal.

I was able to open the record in complete new window using the below code:

```
<td><a href="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ acp.Id + '/view'}" target="_blank">{!acp.Name }</a></td>
```

But when i try to create a modal component and a button in the datatable to open the modal, i am not able to pass the record id to the modal. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add the code for the modal component and button to the question so that we can see what is causing the problem. See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

To open the record edit page in modal you should use [force:editRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_editRecord.htm) event. This opens the page to edit the record specified by **recordId**.

Call this event on the click of an anchor link inside the table and attach the Id value to the anchor via a `data-` attribute and fetch it in the controller from the `event.currentTarget` as below.

Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" >
    <table class="slds-table">
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Id</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td><a onclick="{!c.editRecord}" data-value="0036F000023sSzDQAU">0036F000023sSzDQAU</a></td></tr>
            <tr><td><a onclick="{!c.editRecord}" data-value="0036F000023sSzLQAU">0036F000023sSzLQAU</a></td></tr>
            <tr><td><a onclick="{!c.editRecord}" data-value="0036F000023sSzMQAU">0036F000023sSzMQAU</a></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    editRecord: function (cmp, event) {
        var rectarget = event.currentTarget;
        var idstr = rectarget.getAttribute("data-value"); 
        var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
        editRecordEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": idstr
        });
        editRecordEvent.fire();        
    }
})
```

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to load a different record type's layout instead of the default layout in the same situation?

Comment: This is edit mode and based on record Id it will load the page layout according to record type. You can't change the record type in runtime.